# Edit Custom Metadata Records from a Managed Package

Tags: managed-package, metadata-api, customsetting, custom-metadata

Custom metadata records seem to be great mechanism to store application configuration details, as unlike Custom objects or Custom settings, custom metadata records can be packaged with a managed package, and easily upgraded with subsequent releases.

However, it seems that (at least for now) custom metadata records can not be updated via APEX.

Is it possible to update custom metadata records from a managed package using Metadata API? If so, are there any examples out there?

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to edit *subscriber-controlled fields* on *public* records of *public* custom metadata types via the metadata API, even if those records are included in a managed package. The main thing you need to remember is that both the type and the record will have a namespace in this case, so if they come from the same managed package, the full name of the record will be

packagens__TheType.packagens__TheRecord

**Update for Summer 17:**

Starting in Summer 17, you can asynchronously edit *subscriber-controlled* fields on public *or* protected records of public *or* protected types, so long as they're visible to your package's code (so, public or in your package or using your package's type), without needing to perform a callout, using the new Metadata package in Apex. You can also create new records of public or protected types--but note that new records are creating into the subscriber's namespace, not yours, so the only way to keep them hidden is if their *type* is protected and installed.