# Metadata.DeployCallback is not called when deployment status is Fatal Error

Tags: deployment, metadata, custom-metadata

### BACKGROUND

I am working on a feature that deploys custom metadata record. I am using  a scratch org with a linked namespace.

This is a my method which initiates deployment:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String deployDemo()
{
    Metadata.CustomMetadata customMetadataRecord;
    List<String> componentNameList = new List<String>{'mynamespace__ObjectSetting__mdt.mynamespace__Config'};
    List<Metadata.Metadata> components = Metadata.Operations.retrieve(Metadata.MetadataType.CustomMetadata, componentNameList);
    customMetadataRecord = (Metadata.CustomMetadata)components.get(0);

    Metadata.CustomMetadataValue customField = new Metadata.CustomMetadataValue();
    customField.field = 'mynamespace__Objects__c';
    customField.value = 'dummy text';
    customMetadataRecord.values.add(customField);

    Metadata.DeployContainer mdContainer = new Metadata.DeployContainer();
    mdContainer.addMetadata(customMetadataRecord);
    ID jobID = Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment(mdContainer, new MetadataDeployCallback());

    return String.valueOf(jobID);
}
```

And here the implementation of `Metadata.DeployCallback`:

```
public with sharing class MetadataDeployCallback implements Metadata.DeployCallback
{
    public void handleResult(Metadata.DeployResult result, Metadata.DeployCallbackContext context)
    {
        System.debug('MetadataDeployCallback with DeployResult ' + JSON.serialize(result));
        System.debug('MetadataDeployCallback with DeployCallbackContext ' + JSON.serialize(context));

        MetadataDeployComplete__e mdEvent = new MetadataDeployComplete__e();
        mdEvent.Success__c = result.success;
        mdEvent.JobID__c = result.id;
        mdEvent.Status__c = String.valueOf(result.status);

        if(result.status != Metadata.DeployStatus.Succeeded)
        {
            // Verbose error handling is skipped for brevity
            mdEvent.ErrorMessage__c = 'Error';
        }

        Database.SaveResult eventResult = EventBus.publish(mdEvent);
        if( !eventResult.success)
        {
            system.debug('Failed to publish event');
        }
    }
}
```

### PROBLEM

Every time I call the `deployDemo()` method I get a valid jobID value. However, the `handleResult` from the `MetadataDeployCallback` class is invoked only when deployment is Successful. If a deployment has been completed with Fatal Error, `handleResult` is never executed (*this is my observation based on absence of debug logs* ). What is more, this issue occurs randomly, sometimes deployment is successful, sometimes it ends up with fatal error.

[image]

[image]

### QUESTION

Why is Metadata.DeployCallback not called when deployment status is Fatal Error?
And why does deployments fail randomly? If there was an error in the code, I would expect it to fail all the time.

### RELATED QUESTIONS

[Cannot update packaged custom metadata records from packaged Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/213006/cannot-update-packaged-custom-metadata-records-from-packaged-apex)

[Edit Custom Metadata Records from a Managed Package](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/126992/edit-custom-metadata-records-from-a-managed-package)

[Cannot update Custom Metadata records from Subscriber org in managed app](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/253867/cannot-update-custom-metadata-records-from-subscriber-org-in-managed-app)

Comment: Have you opened Salesforce support case?

Comment: No, because I don't have a Salesforce org, unfortunately. I use free developer orgs, which are not covered by support.

Comment: @Patlatus, do you know, by chance, how can I reach support in my case? Is it even possible?

Comment: They would refuse the ticket if you don't open it from client account with premier support

Comment: Yes, that's why I cannot reach out to support.